# Lua get day of year

Tags: lua

I am trying to write a script that determines stardate using the formula

```
a = LastLeapYearShort (if year is leap year make 4 years ago)
b = 366 + (365 * ((CurrentYearShort - 1) - LastLeapYearShort)
c = DayOfYear - DayOfMonth
d = DayOfMonth
e = (SecondOfMinute + (MinuteOfHour * 60))/1440
f = 36525
st = ((a + b + c + d + e)/f)*100000

separate x.y into x and y

if the century is greater than 19 add 1- to the beginning of x and get the first to digits of y

date = x.y
```

however I can't seem to determine a way to get `DayOfYear`. The Current Script I have is

```
function isLeapYear(year)
  return year%4==0 and (year%100~=0 or year%400==0)
end

function lastLeapYear(year)
  if(isLeapYear(year))
    result = strsub(year,2,4) - 4
  else
    year = year - 1
    if(isLeapYear(year))
      result = strsub(year,2,4)
    else
      year = year - 1
      if(isLeapYear(year))
        result = strsub(year,2,4)
      else
        year = year - 1
        if(isLeapYear(year))
          result = strsub(year,2,4)
        else
          result = "Invalid"
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return result
end

function stardate()
  yearf = os.date("%Y")
  yearh = os.date("%y")

  a = lastLeapYear(yearf)
  b = (366 + (365 * (yearh - a)))
  c = (!!DayOfYear!! - os.date("%d"))
  d = os.date("%d")
  e = (os.date("%S") + (os.date("%M") * 60))/1440
  f = 36525
  st = ((a + b + c + d + e)/f)*100000
  !!Separate st into x and y!!

  if(strsub(yearf,0,2) > 19)
    diff = strsub(yearf,0,2) - 19

    lead = diff "-" lead
  end

  return lead.dec
end
```

if there are any other errors in my code please point them out as I have very little Lua experience.

Comment: "if there are any other errors in my code" -> Use `local` variables. What version of lua? Have you looked at the available format strings for use with `date`/etc.?

Comment: @EtanReisner the script is for use in rainmeter so I don't actually know what version. And as I said I don't know much about LUA so how do I declare a local variable?? and yes I have I couldn't find something about finding the day of the year.

Answer (score 4):

The day of year is the value of `os.date("*t").yday` or `os.date("%j")`.

The first expression gives you a number; the second one gives you a string (which can be converted explicitly to a number with `tonumber` or implicitly when used in an arithmetic operation).

Answer (score 0):

For any one who can't find the proper format string a more advanced list than that on http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html (which is where I was looking) can be found on http://docs.rainmeter.net/manual/measures/time